# Trying to deploy a Rails 4 app to WebFaction, using their documentation and getting an error locally

Tags: ruby-on-rails, capistrano, webfaction, rvm-capistrano

I am trying to deploy a Rails 4 app via github to Webfaction via Capistrano 2.15.5. Initially I installed Capistrano 3 and was getting errors, so I ended up installing Capistrano 2.15.5 and following webfaction's documentation [here](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/rails.html#deploying-a-ruby-on-rails-application-with-capistrano):

I spoke with webfaction, and they suggested I try the older Cap 2 version since that's what they're familiar with and wouldn't be updating their documentation for Capistrano 3 for awhile.

I get through all the appropriate steps in their tutorial, and I get a bunch of errors when trying to run "cap deploy:setup" or "cap deploy:check" etc.

Errors in a pastebin, [here](http://pastebin.com/zbUfa9m0): (and shown below)

```
/Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/setup (LoadError)
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
    from Capfile:6:in `load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:180:in `load_from_file'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `block in load_recipes'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>' 
galactica% cap deploy:check
/Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require': cannot load such file -- capistrano/setup (LoadError)
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:152:in `require'
    from Capfile:6:in `load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `instance_eval'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:93:in `load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:180:in `load_from_file'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:89:in `load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `block in load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `each'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/configuration/loading.rb:86:in `load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `block in load_recipes'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `each'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:65:in `load_recipes'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:31:in `execute!'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/lib/capistrano/cli/execute.rb:14:in `execute'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/gems/capistrano-2.15.5/bin/cap:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `load'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/cap:23:in `<main>'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I've tried looking into the files, but I'm unsure really of what the issue is, and I dont know enough ruby to troubleshoot. I was hoping you of you could help me.

Any help would be IMMENSELY appreciated and gittipp'ed!!  :)

Thank you in advance! 
~Josh

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing you set up your project's configuration with Capistrano 3, and I think the setup for Capistrano 2 is different.

I'm not too familiar with the differences, but the error you're getting is `cannot load such file -- capistrano/setup` and [this post](https://medium.com/p/ba896a142ac) about capistrano 3 references `require 'capistrano/setup'` as being in the `Capfile` that capistrano 3 generates.

So I'm guessing that file doesn't exist for capistrano 2. I don't know if capistrano 2 has generators that you could run and let them overwrite the files you have, but if it does, try that?

Or try taking out that line and see if you get a different error? Or revert the commit(s) where you started setting up capistrano 3 and start the configuration process completely over with capistrano 2?

Comment: I stand corrected, (from Twitter.) I followed your steps, deleting old files and adding a new gemset and then running from that, and rerunning capify and going through my old deploy.rb and adding stuff back in.

The only issue now is a error on not connecting, and i think that that;s based on my own syntax...

Answer (score 0):

Have you installed Capistrano 2 using "gem install" under your ruby v2.0?

rvm 2.0.0
gem install capistrano "your version"

Try this first....

Comment: Hi Jae,
yeah, I did that, and I just checked my gem environment with "gem env" and that is indeed where the gems themselves live, is in these directories


GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247
     - /Users/aronoff/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@global  


So strange...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error while deploying my rails 4 application using cap 2.15.5. I did research and found out that the problem was syntax as i switched from cap 3 to cap 2. So if you are using cap v2 only load command work in capfile and Require commands are used only in deploy.rb . So if you are switching from 3 to 2, do keep in mind the syntax as there are lots of changes between cap v2 and cap v3.

**Note**: For deploying rails 4 application 2.15.5 is the stable capistrano version you can use. Here is the guide link that worked for me : https:[//gist.github.com/brobertsaz/8660415](https://gist.github.com/brobertsaz/8660415)