# Errors when deploying a rails 4 app onto Web Faction

Tags: ruby-on-rails, webfaction

Ok, here goes. In a previous question, I had asked how to set up a rails 4 app from github to web faction. I was successful after doing several things.

Here's that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20228193/trying-to-deploy-a-rails-4-app-to-webfaction-using-their-documentation-and-gett).

Part II of this whole process, is I am having errors AFTER deployment.

Here's the [site](http://celebritypettingzoo.com/) I'm referencing.
Here's the [repository on github](https://github.com/jaronoff/new_site) that I am pulling from for deploying.

Here's the steps I took to deploy:
1) [followed the rails documentation on webfaction's how to](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/rails.html).
2) Added ssh forward agent and the appropriate keys to GitHub to use my local ssh keys for deployment.
3) Changed the appropriate forward agent status to yes in the nginx.conf file.
4) run Cap deploy... moves files to appropriate folder within application.
5) go to celebritypettingzoo.com (just a placeholder till i get the site up and running.) get the error seen there.
6) run rake db:migrate, nothing happens.
7) come back today, try and run it again, and then unable to because of this error:
`"ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Errno::EACCES) Permission denied - /home/jaronoff/webapps/gems"`
8) Set up a database and change my `database.yml` file to point to the new database that's referenced [here](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/rails.html#using-a-database-with-a-ruby-on-rails-application).
9) Go to step 6 in ["Installing Multiple Gems with Bundler"](http://docs.webfaction.com/software/rails.html#installing-multiple-gems-with-bundler) and get the same error from step 7) above.

So, my questions:

- Am I missing something in this whole process that I should be doing that's fundamental to deployment? Keep in mind I'm green, and some of these elementary steps are lost on me.
- If I am able to get these server issues figured out, and get the database.yml file, pointing to the proper database on the server, if I run rake db:migrate, it will basically create a migration for all the models in my models folder?
- Lastly, should I put my database.yml file in my gemlock file, so as to not cause security issues? Is that something you don't want to include but overwrite manually on the server? I ended up doing that, but if I add it back into github, I think that currently it will just include my production credentials in that file.

Thank you in advance for the help! I'm new to all this, but learning a lot! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was actually able to accomplish this task, by redoing the deployment in a brand new rails application on the server!

Comment: I have to wait 15 hours, then i will. Thanks Majioa!

Comment: I think it has been 15 hours.